# ListView with Dimensions.get

Tags: listview, react-native

I am trying to display a list of images using ListView.

ListView code:

```
      <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)} enableEmptySections={true} removeClippedSubviews={true}> > </ListView>
```

Images are displayed with this code:

```
_renderItem(item) {
    return (
            <ListItem item={item}/>
            );
     }
```

ListItem.js

```
render() {
    return (

            <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}  style={styles.displayImage} source={{ uri: this.props.item.name }} />

            );
}
```

Styles:

```
 const React = require('react-native')
 const {StyleSheet} = React

 import {
         Dimensions
        } from 'react-native';

 var styles = StyleSheet.create({
                           displayImage: {
                           backgroundColor: 'blue',
                           height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                           width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                           padding: 5,
                           },

 })

 module.exports = styles
```

However, when the images are displayed, only one image is displayed on the screen and I have to scroll down to see the next image. I know this is because of using height and width. I am using height and width in styles so I don't have to deal with resizing the image on different size devices. Is it possible to display the next item in the list right below it with a some space between the two images ?

Screen Shot displaying one image. I have to scroll down to see next image. I would like to display the next image right below the first image.

[image: Screen Shot displaying one image. I have to scroll down to see next image. I would like to display the next image right below the first image.]

Comment: This is most likely a styling issue. Please add more code to show your `_renderItem` and your styling.

Comment: Edited code to include _renderItem and styling. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Still not enough to say something. You create styles but not implementing anywhere. Whats in the `ListItem` Compoent?

Comment: Oops ... edited code to include ListItem.js's render.

Comment: do you know the original height of the image you add? try removing height from the style.

Comment: No. But can vary. Removing height doesn't display anything at all. So I changed height to 400. The issue remains. I have to scroll down to see next image.

Comment: You need to calculate and set the image height. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize) you can find how to get size of an image. Then you can calculate the aspect ratio and set the height of the image.